# How do I position the nav in the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to position the navbar in the center of the page in css. I wrote css as nav, ul, li and a

I tried text-align: center; on nav, nav ul, nav ul li, nav ul li a, but all these didn't work.

I only hope there is another property to use

Comment: Post relevant code. No one can inspect the issue without proper code.

Comment: `text-*` works for .. _well_ .. text nodes, not for block elements

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
.wrapper{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Now every item in the .wrapper gets centered vertically and horizontally. You can of course style your wrapper in any way you want. If you want it to fill the whole screen, use `height: 100vh;` & `width: 100vw;`. Don't forget to put your nav inside of a div with the .wrapper class in your HTML file.

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding!

Comment: OP can just put the wrapper around it, or apply the properties to the parent element.